# spring boot unable to read application.yml

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot unable to read application.yml when I customize the maven-resources-plugin configuration. Because I want to replace some strings in Dockerfile with variables in pom.xml,
Any one knows how to do it? Really appreciate!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-docker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>k8s</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>Dockerfile</include>
                            </includes>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

in dockerfile I want to replace these strings below

```
....
ADD ./@project.build.finalName@.jar /root/@project.build.finalName@.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/root/@project.build.finalName@.jar"]
```

Comment: I deleted my answer. Please add your finding as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it work by config like this:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>-->
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>k8s</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>Dockerfile</include>
                            </includes>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true resources:resources
**src/main/resources** is requried when mvn package